# CSS images showing blank?

Tags: css, perl

I have a small Perl script the loads some external images to page. The images links (50 of them) are all within an array which I iterate through to dump to screen. While I am reasonably good at Perl I have never done any web dev before so I am a complete noob with CSS. I have the following code in the html template

```
[% FOREACH dvd IN dvd_chart %]

<div class="thumbnail">
<img  src="[% dvd.thumbnail %]" />
<br>
</div>

[% END %]
```

The CSS is this:

```
.thumbnail
{
float: left;
width: 120px;
border: 1px solid #999;
margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
padding: 5px;
}
```

EDIT:
Generated HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
<img  src="http://content9.flixster.com/movie/11/16/78/11167831_pro.jpg" />
<br>
Taken 2
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
<img  src="http://content9.flixster.com/movie/11/16/86/11168615_pro.jpg" />
<br>
The Possession
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
<img  src="http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/16/80/11168037_pro.jpg" />
<br>
Won't Back Down
</div>
<div class="thumbnail">
<img  src="http://content9.flixster.com/movie/11/16/51/11165143_pro.jpg" />
<br>
To Rome with Love
</div
```

The problem is the images start to load perfectly, the first two rows are fine, but then there will be a few rows with just one image, followed by more good rows. There are no missing URLs. Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong or even a good tutorial for loading dynamic images into div -that wraps!

Comment: do you have a live link? or example?

Comment: Try to set the height to the .thumbnail or inspect the element and check if the image is being loaded f.e...

Comment: Okay, can you show us the generated HTML?

Comment: Please say what module you are using. `Template::Toolkit`?

Comment: The site is internal at the moment but I've edited the original post to show the HTML, it reapeats like that for 50 rows. Yes, I am using Template::Toolkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at your HTML and CSS in a JS fiddle, and I saw right away that it's an issue with the height of any item with a longer movie title. A quick Google search for "CSS gallery variable height" brings up this tutorial: http://jonathanweatherhead.com/2012/12/31/how-to-make-a-flowing-css-gallery-layout/

I would follow that. Otherwise, you may have to set a height for all gallery items (not the best plan) or limit the length of the movie titles (also not great).